# ui activity indicator is not showing up in viewcontroller, in which it has table view and web view?

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, uiactivityindicatorview

```
var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
 actInd.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
   actInd.center = view.center
actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
 view.addSubview(actInd)
getinfo()
actInd.startAnimating()
func getinfo(){
 //in this function theres is few image parsing codes, for table view

for i in 0 ..< minuscurent1.count
    {
        let adict:NSDictionary = minuscurent1[i] as! NSDictionary

        let bdict:NSDictionary = adict.object(forKey: "snippet") as! NSDictionary
        let cdict:NSDictionary = bdict.object(forKey: "resourceId") as! NSDictionary
        let ddict:NSDictionary = bdict.object(forKey: "thumbnails") as! NSDictionary
        let edict:NSDictionary = ddict.object(forKey: "medium") as! NSDictionary

        self.videolist.add(bdict.object(forKey: "title") as! String)
        self.videoId.add(cdict.object(forKey: "videoId") as! String)
        self.image.add(edict.object(forKey: "url") as! String)
    }
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.actInd.stopAnimating()
            self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
            self.videotable.reloadData()
        }
```

i want the activity indicator to start from beginning and end it when all the images and web view is loaded.but the activity indicator is not showing up.i don't know what is wrong with the code.any help is appreciated...

Comment: Show the code you have written for downloading/loading the images.

Comment: see this for e.g : https://gkbrown.org/2015/12/07/displaying-an-activity-indicator-while-loading-data-in-the-background/

Comment: Does your parsing happen on the main-thread? If so, it will block the UI from updating and the activity-indicator won't show until it has finished parsing.

Comment: change the execution order, to actInd.startAnimating(), getinfo()

Comment: @TMob i have edited the code shown above now it has the parsing code.the get info function gets called from view did load

Comment: @LalKrishna changed it still not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image-loading is happening in the main-thread, thus blocking the UI from updating. You have to do the heavy work in a background thread and only update the activity-indicator once youre done.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Background Thread
    // put your image loading here (for-loop)


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Run UI Updates
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
        self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.videotable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the activity-indicator visible? Like in is it not .isHidden = true

Comment: i have not used ishidden in my code,should i use it and where

Comment: No you shouldn't. It would have been an explanation why you don't see the inidicator. What view are you adding it to? Did you consider adding it via storyboard?

Comment: i am adding it to main view. and i have tried it using storyboard 1st didnt work.,so coded it

Comment: I suggest trying it via storyboard again. It just gives you a lot more control than just adding it to the main-view.